# Should there be a tag for [regional-differences]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few questions on Movies & TV about regional differences between releases of a movie.

- [Why "Moana" is called "Vaiana" in Europe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/74499/48480)
- [Why and to which extent was The Night Manager recut for international release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52317/48480)
- [Why change translation text into a picture for international versions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64336/48480)
- [Why was the title changed to Dark Kingdom in the German release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13508/48480)
- [What is the difference to the international version of the Twin Peaks pilot and why is there a difference?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66838/48480)
- [What are the reasons behind the shorter Italian version of Cool Hand Luke?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46927/48480)
- [Why did Zootopia change newscasters based on country?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49859/48480)
- [What are the 7 cuts made in the Indian version of Deadpool?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47693/48480)
- [Why are brand names in Hindi TV series censored?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47504/48480)

I was surprised that there wasn't a shared tag for these posts. I'd like to ask whether or not a [regional-differences](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional-differences) tag should be created for questions like this.

If the community thinks a [regional-differences](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional-differences) tag shouldn't be added, an alternative would be to synonymize the tag with [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version), as it would also be appropriate for most of these.

Answer (score 5):

The tag wiki for [alternate-version](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-version) reads..

> An alternate edit to a film (or less commonly, a TV show) which may include new or deleted scenes, removing or re-ordering existing scenes or updating special effects.

This seems to fit...so a **synonym** with a new tag [regional-diiferences](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional-diiferences) does not seem unreasonable.

Comment: Would the tag be applicable for questions about alternate movie titles? (i.e. *[Why "Moana" is called "Vaiana" in Europe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/74499/48480)*

Comment: I don't see why not...if used in conjunction with the [tag:title] tag.